# Passing variables to anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is something I've needed to learn for a while and I'm wondering if any javascript experts can point me in the right direction.

Many libraries I've used seem to accept function pointers as arguments, such as a hook for success, fail, etc.  Here is a simple example of this in an application I'm working on:

```
$('.clock-btn').each(function(){
$(this).click(function(){
    $.ajax(
        {
            url:'punch.php?task_id=' + $(this).data('task-id'),
            success: function() {
                reverseCSS($(this));
            },
            error: function() {
                window.alert("Clocking time to this project is not allowed.");
            }
        }
    );
});
```

});

Where the `reverseCSS()` function is a function that will change the button to an animation and exchange the words with 'clock-in/clock-out' depending on what it was previously.

However, I cannot gain access to the $(this) variable in the `$.ajax` call.  This is expected behavior to me, as I know in this example, the `$(this)` will be the `$.ajax object`, not the item I need from the html.

So, what would be the best method here to access the `$(this)` item?

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Add a variable before your ajax call : var mythis = $(this) and pass mythis to function

Comment: By the way , you can still optimize your code by replacing the double close with a single with `$('.clock-btn').click(function()....`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what `bind()` function does:

```
$('.clock-btn').each(function(){
$(this).click(function(){
    $.ajax(
        {
            url:'punch.php?task_id=' + $(this).data('task-id'),
            success: function() {
                reverseCSS($(this));
            }.bind(this)
        }
    );
});
```

it simply returns a function which is always running in a context you give it, in this case the context is `this`

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

Comment: Ah, the bind method!  I've seen this in places but never took the effort to read more about it.  Thank you so much!

Comment: you are welcome, in ES6 it is even going to be way easier with so called arrow functions, see e.g. here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: the bind method is not compatible with the some old browser .

Comment: Although you are talking about ancient browsers which nobody supports, you can always use polyfill, e.g. see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: @simon Yes, you are right. Today does not worth supporting old browser like IE, most web technologies are focus on modern features

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of:

```
$(this).click(function() {
  var $self = $(this);

  $.ajax({
    url:'punch.php?task_id=' + $(this).data('task-id'),
      success: function() {
        reverseCSS($self);
      },

      // ...
```

Comment: This is a useful answer, and I probably should have stated that I am trying to find out how to access it without creating temporary variables.  Hopefully this helps someone else, though!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.clock-btn').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        var that = this; // save it to another variable
        $.ajax({
            url:'punch.php?task_id=' + $(this).data('task-id'),
            success: function() {
                reverseCSS($(that));
            },
            error: function() {
                window.alert("Clocking time to this project is not allowed.");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: A useful answer. Thanks.